# My bib items are getting sorted in the first name of the author, but I want this with the second name

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, natbib, sorting

Please see below, a snapshot of my reference list:

**References**

Najla Aissaoui, Mohamed Haouari, and Elkafi Hassini.  Supplier selection and order lot sizingmodeling: A review.Computers & operations research, 34(12):3516–3540, 2007.

Amir Hossein Azadnia, Muhamad Zameri Mat Saman, and Kuan Yew Wong. Sustainable sup-plier selection and order lot-sizing: an integrated multi-objective decision-making process.International Journal of Production Research, 53(2):383–408, 2015.

Chuda Basnet and Janny MY Leung.  Inventory lot-sizing with supplier selection.Computers& Operations Research, 32(1):1–14, 2005.Gabriel R Bitran and Horacio H Yanasse.  Computational complexity of the capacitated lotsize problem.Management Science, 28(10):1174–1186, 1982.

Sohail S Chaudhry, Frank G Forst, and James L Zydiak.  Vendor selection with price breaks.European Journal of Operational Research, 70(1):52–66, 1993.

You could see that the references are sorted with the second part of the authors' name. However, I want it with the first letter of the reference. I am using natbib.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show the tex code resulting in your shown screenshot ...

Comment: bibtex will not sort on first names, so it will be an error in your bib file, but it is hard to say how to fix it if you give no information about your current code. My guess would b ethat the authors are entered with commas instead of `and` between the names.

Comment: Assuming that the last names are Aissaoui, Azadnia, Basnet and Chaudhry  the sorting looks ok. Why do you think the sorting is on first names?